# Is it possible to merge 2 IFERROR formulas into 1?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm not sure if it's possible to merge 2 IFERROR formulas into 1. I created 2 combo boxes, in 1 sheet, one for upper and one for sole (footwear) but only "upper" appears on data field because the formula is for upper only.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$B$4:$K$854,'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$N4,COLUMNS($B$4:B4)),"")
the other formula is 
=IFERROR(INDEX('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$B$4:$K$854,'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$Q4,COLUMNS($B$4:B4)),"")
```

Comment: upper is N4 and sole is Q4?

Comment: Yes. I have a another sheet for the list and formula on N4 is =IFERROR(SMALL($M$4:$M$854,L4),"")

Comment: what happened if N4 and Q4 both are having non-zero values?

Comment: it messes up the data field. Data field has 10 columns. 1 column contains numbers (tariff codes), upper, sole, etc. for 1 item on list I used the following codes
=ROWS($C$4:C4) 
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(FOOTWEAR!$C$2,C4)),L4,"")
=IFERROR(SMALL($M$4:$M$854,L4),"")
but since this is for upper, only upper combo box is working since the formula on search result field is =IFERROR(INDEX('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$B$4:$K$854,'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$N4,COLUMNS($B$4:B4)),"") only

Comment: without a sample data.. I can only assume how the really set up look like.. || my method will be.. make sure only either only N4 have value or only Q4 have value.. but not both. Before executing the formula..|| like this.. `=IFERROR(INDEX('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$B$4:$K$854,if(AND('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$N4>0,or('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$Q4=0,'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$Q4="")),'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$N4,if(AND('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$Q4>0,or('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$N4=0,'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$N4="")),'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$N4,-1)),COLUMNS($B$4:B4)),"")` || If you don't mind.. u may share the sample file with the comboBox set up to clarify the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your formula should be written like this:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$B$4:$K$854,'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$N4,COLUMNS($B$4:B4)),INDEX('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$B$4:$K$854,'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$Q4,COLUMNS($B$4:B4)))
```

**How it works:**

- `Two IFERROR` are not required since 
  the `Second`INDEX is working as
  `Value_If_Error` part of `IFERROR`.

**Or, in case if both Index Failed to be true then you may use your Formula like this:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$B$4:$K$854,'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$N4,COLUMNS($B$4:B4)),IFERROR(INDEX('FOOTWEAR CODES'!$B$4:$K$854,'FOOTWEAR CODES'!$Q4,COLUMNS($B$4:B4)),""))
```

**How it works:**

- If both `INDEX` fails to be `TRUE` then 
  Formula will return `BLANK` as
  `Value_If_Error`.

Comment: Glad to help you @em09 ,,, keep asking ☺